# Cordial Labeling of 4-regular graphs

Tags: reference-request, graph-theory

My group is working on ***Cordial Labeling** of 4-regular graphs.
We were wondering if someone here knows whether this study has been done before. 
If not, can someone help me how to know if the given 4-regular graph admits a cordial labeling or not.

Thanks in advance.

please help, it will be much appreciated.

A function f:V→{0,1} is said to be a cordial labeling if each edge uv has the label │f(u)-f(v)│ such that,
(1)The number of vertices labeled ‘0’ and the number of vertices labeled ‘1’ differ by at most “one” denoted as ││V1│-│V0││≤1.
(2)The number of edges labeled ‘0’ and the number of edges labeled ‘1’ differ by at most “one” denoted as ││E1│-│E0││≤1.
A graph which admits cordial labelings is called cordial.

My second question is, If i was given a 4-regular graph, how will I know if it admits a cordial labeling.

Comment: If you want to get a useful answer, you might want to define what is meant by *cordial labeling*. Also when you say "the given 4-regular graph", are you referring to a particular graph? or do you mean *a* given 4-regular graph?

Comment: A function f:V→{0,1} is said to be a cordial labeling if each edge uv has the label │f(u)-f(v)│ such that, (1)The number of vertices labeled ‘0’ and the number of vertices labeled ‘1’ differ by at most “one” denoted as ││V1│-│V0││≤1. (2)The number of edges labeled ‘0’ and the number of edges labeled ‘1’ differ by at most “one” denoted as ││E1│-│E0││≤1.
A graph which admits cordial labeling is called cordial.

i'm sorry, i mean, a given 4-regular graph..

Comment: @MelanieAtendido, you should add this definition in the post. Also, please help us understand your second question about "the given 4-regular" graph. It is very vague.

Comment: I'm sorry, I edited it.

Comment: Since a 4-regular graph has an even number of edges, it seems to me that $||E_0|-|E_1||\le 1$ implies $|E_0|=|E_1|$. Correct?

Comment: @BrendanMcKay not for all. I mean, |E_0|=|E_1| is only true for some 4-regular graph with even order.

Comment: A quartic graph with $n$ vertices has $2n$ edges. If two numbers differ by at most 1 and sum to $2n$, they are both equal to $n$. What am I missing?

Comment: @BrendanMcKay Can you give me some examples of what you are saying? Thank you.

Comment: Let $e_0=|E_0|$ and $e_1=|E_1|$.  Since $e_0+e_1$ is the number of edges, which is even for a quartic graph, then $e_0-e_1$ is also even.  So $|e_0-e_1|$ can't be equal to 1.

Comment: @BrendanMcKay but |E0|=|E1| is not always true for all 4 regular graphs especially having an odd order. 
For example, 4 regular graph of order 7 will have a 2n edges which is equal to 14. from our observation, ││E1│-│E0││≥ 2. 
please kindly correct me if I'm wrong. Thanks

Comment: I never said that $e_0=e_1$ for all labellings.  I said it is true for all cordial labellings.

Comment: @BrendanMcKay oh, I'm m sorry.  If you ever have ideas or knowledge about it, please feel free to comment, it will be our pleasure. Thank you :D

Answer (score 2):

Eulerian graphs with $e$ edges cannot be cordial unless $e$ is a multiple of $4$ so don't bother looking at $4$-regular graphs with an odd number of vertices. (This is in Cahit's original paper that is freely available online).

Comment: Do you know what is the use/sense of graph labelings such as labeling like this, cordial labeling?
Or what/where that is applies to?
And why is it that the graph should be labeled (0,1) to be considered cordial? I mean, will it affect anything? or will have an error if it's not 0 and 1?
Thanks.

Comment: There are hundreds of different types of graph labelling, some of which are motivated by a particular real-world application, while others seem to be totally made up just in order to have something to study. I think you'd have to research the origins of cordial labelling to see whether it is interesting and useful to you or not. I don't do anything with graph labellings myself.